# Datastructure for creating indexes in database

Tags: database, database-design

Can HashTables be used to create indexes in databases? What is the ideal Data structure to create indexes?
If a table has has a foreign key referencing a field in other database does will it help if we create index on the foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can HashTables be used to create indexes in databases?

Some DBMSes support hash-based indexes, some don't.

> What is the ideal Data structure to create indexes?

No data structure occupies 0 bytes, nor it can be manipulated in 0 CPU cycles, therefore no data structure is "ideal". It is upon us, the software engineers, to decide which data structure has most benefits and fewest detriments to the specific goal we are trying to accomplish.

For example, B-Trees are useful for range scans and hash indexes aren't. Does that mean the B-Trees are "better"? Well, they are if you need range scans, but may not necessarily be if you don't.

> If a table has has a foreign key referencing a field in other database does will it help if we create index on the foreign key?

You can not normally have a foreign key toward another *database*, only another table.

And yes, it tends to help, since every time a row is updated or deleted in the parent table, the child table needs to be searched to see if the FK was violated. This search can significantly benefit from such an index. Many (but not all) DBMSes require index on FK (and might even create it automatically if not already there).

OTOH, if you only add rows to the parent table, you could consider leaving the child table unindexed on FK fields (assuming your DBMS allows you to do so).

Comment: Why is B-Tree based index more useful for range scans?

Comment: @bourne In short, because it physically sorts the keys. Once a key is located, getting the "physically next" key is equivalent to getting the "logically next" key. So a query with `WHERE X >= :min AND X <= :max` can be satisfied by first locating `:min`, and then going forward until `:max` is encountered. Please familiarize yourself with the structure of B-Trees and the understanding of their performance characteristics will follow naturally.

Comment: Can you please point me to a good implementation of B-Tree or a good tutorial? I did try reading B-Trees in CLR but it was difficult to understand insertion, deletion. Also I'm not clear on how the "Physically next" key is the "logically next" key? The "logically next key" could possibly be in a different sub tree of the B Tree.

Comment: @bourne Take a look at the [Anatomy of an SQL Index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy) at Use The Index, Luke!

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Perspective**

Oracle supports clustering by hash value, either for single or multiple tables. This physically colocates rows having the same hash value for the cluster columns, and is faster than accessing via an index. There are disadvantages due to increased complexity and a certain need for preplanning.

You could also use a function-based index to index based on a hash function applied to one or more columns. I'm not sure what the advantage of that would be though.

Foreign key columns in Oracle generally benefit from indexing due to the obvious performance advantages.

Comment: I'd only add that, historically, some dbms automatically index foreign key columns and don't allow dropping those indexes; some automatically index foreign key columns and *do* allow dropping those indexes; and some don't automatically index foreign key columns. (OP didn't say which dbms.)